# Jetpack Compose, How do I manage derived, nested state in a view model?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've got a UI with multiple spinners, where the options in one spinner depend on the selection in another. I also have "Next" and "Back" buttons that progress through all options so I can easily update various data related to all combinations of the spinner options. The issue is that when I update the dependee spinner to a value that changes the dependent spinner, the UI loses track of the state after a recomposition. I know I'm obviously tracking something incorrectly, but I'm at a loss as to what specifically is missing. Here's the code:

```
class CalibratingViewModel {
    companion object {
        val SHORT_KINDS = listOf("Min", "Mid", "Max")
        val LONG_KINDS = listOf("Home", "Min", "Mid", "Max")
    }

    val jointListModel = SpinnerViewModel(
        options = listOf("Coxa", "Femur", "Tibia"), label = "Joint"
    )

    private val kindOptions by derivedStateOf {
        when (jointListModel.selected.intValue) {
            // Coxa or Femur
            0, 1 -> SHORT_KINDS
            // Tibia
            2 -> LONG_KINDS
            else -> throw Exception("Invalid joint ${jointListModel.selected.intValue}")
        }
    }

    val kindListModel = SpinnerViewModel(
        label = "Calibration Kind", options = kindOptions
    )

    fun next() {
        if (kindListModel.selected.intValue == kindListModel.options.size - 1) {
            if (jointListModel.selected.intValue == jointListModel.options.size - 1) {
                jointListModel.selected.intValue = 0
            } else {
                jointListModel.selected.intValue += 1
            }
            kindListModel.selected.intValue = 0
        } else {
            kindListModel.selected.intValue += 1
        }
    }

    fun prev() {
        if (kindListModel.selected.intValue == 0) {
            if (jointListModel.selected.intValue == 0) {
                jointListModel.selected.intValue = jointListModel.options.size - 1
            } else {
                jointListModel.selected.intValue -= 1
            }
            kindListModel.selected.intValue = kindListModel.options.size - 1
        } else {
            kindListModel.selected.intValue -= 1
        }
    }
}

@Parcelize
class SpinnerViewModel(
    val options: List<String>,
    val label: String,
    val selected: @RawValue MutableIntState = mutableIntStateOf(0),
    val expanded: @RawValue MutableState<Boolean> = mutableStateOf(false)
) : Parcelable

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Spinner(
    viewModel: SpinnerViewModel,
    onSelected: () -> Unit = {},
) {
    var expanded by remember { viewModel.expanded }
    var selected by remember { viewModel.selected }
    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(expanded = expanded, onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded }) {
        TextField(
            readOnly = true,
            value = viewModel.options[selected],
            onValueChange = {},
            label = { Text(text = viewModel.label) },
            trailingIcon = {
                ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded)
            },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .menuAnchor()
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }) {
            viewModel.options.forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
                DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text(text = viewModel.options[index]) }, onClick = {
                    selected = index
                    expanded = false
                    onSelected()
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CalibratingView(context: Context, viewModel: CalibratingViewModel) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Column() {
        val kinds = remember {
            viewModel.kindListModel
        }
        Spinner(viewModel.jointListModel)
        Spinner(kinds)
        Row() {
            Button(onClick = {
                viewModel.prev()
            }) {
                Text(text = "Previous")
            }
            Button(onClick = {
                viewModel.next()
            }) {
                Text(text = "Next")
            }
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    context.calibrationDataStore.data.collect {
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            },
        ) {
            Text(text = "Load")
        }
    }
}
```

So current behavior is:
I can press `Next`, and I see the value in the `Kinds` spinner go from `Min` to `Mid` to `Max`. Pressing `Next` again updates `Joints` from `Coxa` to `Femur` and `Kinds` resets to `Min`. I can do this until `Joints` goes from `Femur` to `Tibia`. My understanding is that this triggers the derivedStateOf for the kinds options. After this, the `Next` and `Previous` buttons stop updating the UI. If I add logs to `Next` and `Prev`, they to reset the joints selection to 0 whenever it gets set to `Tibia`.

I tried wrapping `kindListModel` as `val kindListModel by derivedStateOf { Spinner (...) }` since I thought maybe the options needed to be proxied through somehow, but that just causes it to break as soon as joints switches to `Femur` (second option). This also only work if the remember is given a key of the same value it's trying to remember `val kinds by remember(viewModel.kindListModel) { viewModel.kindListModel }`. Interesetingly, the logs in `Next` and `Previous` show that the models are now accurate. `Joints` selection does not get reset to 0. But the UI does not reflect this state. It can still be manually updated, but the `Next` and `Previous` buttons don't seem to affect the UI.

I tried adding various remember states to the joint list model, but this never had any noticeable effect (I didn't keep track of the variations I tried here).

It's also important that I be able to capture the selected spinner entries via the view model. I use them to manage data in bluetooth communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research into how this is done in react and found that the same applies here. The best approach is to not use a view model for spinner, but use explicit parameters instead. The spinner should also not own updating the selected value, but instead should allow the caller to decide whether to update based on the selection index. This allowed me to track the selected values in the main view model instead, and to not have to track the spinner options in such a convoluted manner. The updated code is below:

```kotlin
class CalibratingViewModel {
    companion object {
        val JOINT_OPTIONS = listOf("Coxa", "Femur", "Tibia")
        val SHORT_KIND_OPTIONS = listOf("Min", "Mid", "Max")
        val LONG_KIND_OPTIONS = listOf("Home", "Min", "Mid", "Max")
    }

    val joint = mutableIntStateOf(0)
    val kind = mutableIntStateOf(0)
    val enabled = mutableStateOf(false)
    val pulse = mutableFloatStateOf(1500.0f)

    fun kindOptions(): List<String> {
        return when (joint.intValue) {
            // Coxa or Femur
            0, 1 -> SHORT_KIND_OPTIONS
            // Tibia
            2 -> LONG_KIND_OPTIONS
            else -> throw Exception("Invalid joint ${joint.intValue}")
        }
    }

    fun next() {
        if (kind.intValue == kindOptions().size - 1) {
            if (joint.intValue == JOINT_OPTIONS.size - 1) {
                joint.intValue = 0
            } else {
                joint.intValue += 1
            }
            kind.intValue = 0
        } else {
            kind.intValue += 1
        }
    }

    fun prev() {
        if (kind.intValue == 0) {
            if (joint.intValue == 0) {
                joint.intValue = JOINT_OPTIONS.size - 1
            } else {
                joint.intValue -= 1
            }
            kind.intValue = kindOptions().size - 1
        } else {
            kind.intValue -= 1
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun Spinner(
    label: String,
    options: List<String>,
    selected: Int,
    onSelected: (Int) -> Unit,
) {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(expanded = expanded, onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded }) {
        TextField(
            readOnly = true,
            value = options[selected],
            onValueChange = {},
            label = { Text(text = label) },
            trailingIcon = {
                ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded)
            },
            colors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .menuAnchor()
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(expanded = expanded, onDismissRequest = { expanded = false }) {
            options.forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
                DropdownMenuItem(text = { Text(text = options[index]) }, onClick = {
                    expanded = false
                    onSelected(index)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun CalibratingView(context: Context, viewModel: CalibratingViewModel) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Column() {
        val kind = remember {
            viewModel.kind
        }
        val joint = remember {
            viewModel.joint
        }
        Spinner(options = CalibratingViewModel.JOINT_OPTIONS,
                label = "Joint",
                selected = joint.intValue,
                onSelected = {
                    joint.intValue = it
                })
        Spinner(options = viewModel.kindOptions(),
                label = "Kind",
                selected = kind.intValue,
                onSelected = {
                    kind.intValue = it
                }))
        Row() {
            Button(onClick = {
                viewModel.prev()
            }) {
                Text(text = "Previous")
            }
            Button(onClick = {
                viewModel.next()
            }) {
                Text(text = "Next")
            }
        }
        val context = LocalContext.current
        Button(
            onClick = {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    context.calibrationDataStore.data.collect {
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            },
        ) {
            Text(text = "Load")
        }
    }
}
```